# Regular expression for handling comma separated list with irregular quotes

Tags: regex, string, parsing, regex-lookarounds

I am receiving some pretty ugly data from a source and need to address the issue with a regular expression.  Asking the provider to clean up the data source is not possible.  My data looks like this:

string 1, string 2,,"string,4",string 5

There are two complications here, as I see it.  I need to match the empty string in the 3rd field and I need to capture "string,4" as the 4th field.  The hardest part has been trying to figure out how to handle the comma in the quotes.  I have been playing around with lookahead/lookbehind assertions but haven't had much luck.  Also, while I am not positive, I need to assume that any field can be quoted any time and expect a line such the one below and not expect it to be consistent:

string 1, "string,2",,string 4,string 5

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Is this not standard CSV?  What language are you using?  Surely there is existing CSV-parsing code you can use.

Comment: The Regex flavor in use is PCRE so it does support lookbehinds.  I am trying to test your regexp in some testers (Visual Regexp and pythex.org) but it is invalid for some reason.  I'm trying to work through it now. --edit: someone deleted their comment, probably because the regex was broken.

Comment: @AndyLester I was pretty clear, I think, about what the issue is and what technologies I have available to solve it. But thanks for your contribution.

Comment: The reason Andy's comment is pertinent is because you cannot reliably do this with a regular expression. If you can't use a CSV library, you'll have to write a parser yourself that counts commas and quotes. It's the only way you'll be guaranteed to parse the datasource.

Comment: Hmm, well... looks like the person below nailed it.  So I'd say good job to iismathwizard.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see anything that says what language you are using?

Comment: Maybe you're not thinking of the problem correctly.  Who said I'm using a programming language?  The correct question (someone else asked) is which Regex flavor, to which I answered PCRE.  You should try again, but next time with less snark.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but possibly could use a variation of [The Regex Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

```
"[^"]*"|\w[^",]*
```

[See test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xD5aT8/4); With PCRE if you want to capture the stuff inside quotes, use [branch reset](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
(?|"([^"]*)"|(\w[^",]*))
```

[Test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xD5aT8/5)

Comment: Damn, thanks Jonny!  That's very bad ass.  Works perfectly.  The answer given by iismathwizard is very close but it has some weird capturing going on.  [iismathwizard's regex](https://regex101.com/r/zY7jZ5/2)

Comment: @caranda well, the idea is basically the same :) and welcome

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:(?:\s?([^",]*)|"([^"]*)"),)(?:(?:\s?([^",]*)|"([^"]*)"),)(?:(?:\s?([^",]*)|"([^"]*)"),)(?:(?:\s?([^",]*)|"([^"]*)"),)(?:(?:\s?([^",]*)|"([^"]*)"))
```

---

this works exactly as you want
you can check this at https://regex101.com/r/bZ8xM8/1

Answer (score 0):

This works fairly well for me. Let me know if it needs to be improved

```
((?:".*?")|[^,"]*)
```